# The purpose of having TBLPROPERTIES in create table

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

What is the purpose of using `TBLPROPERTIES("quality" = "silver")` while creating table using `CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE...` syntax. Is it just to tag the table that it is a silver table or does it drive anything else during data processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, similar properties are just for tagging the table, so if necessary you can quickly figure out which tables are belong to which data quality level. This is especially useful right now when all tables are registered in the same database/schema.  And you can add more tags if necessary, for example, to identify subprojects, data sources, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to query all tables having similar tagging? Like LIST TABLES WHERE quality = 'silver'

Comment: you can list tables in the schema/database, and they describe each table. If you use unity catalog, then you should be able to use `information_schema` (not sure although)